# associative array key changes in php for special characters

Tags: php, arrays

This is my sample object. I need to access the object using the array. But i m not able to access the array this scenario, because special character (@) is prefix. so help me how to access the array.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Reference] => 758
            [Key] => P201602161758028991205395
        )

)
```

Comment: Objects !== arrays.... if you need to access the attributes, then use [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: `$obj->{'@attributes'}['Key']`

Comment: Please RTFM, example #5, accessing attributes: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these attributes directly, e.g.

```
echo $elem["Reference"];
echo $elem["Key"];
```

As @Mark Baker pointed in the right direction, the actual magic of `SimpleXML` happens behind the scenes. As @deceze mentionned, this is **specific to SimpleXML**.

You can even loop over them:

```
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo "$a = $b \n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access individual attributes directly as @Jan's answer shows.

If you need to grab all the attributes as a true array, this is one way to do it:

```
$attributes = current($element->attributes());
```

I prefer this as a tight, condensed way to grab all attributes as an array without loops.